# Exporting data.frame to xlsx

Tags: r, excel

I'm working with a data.frame like follows

```
> ResultsFrame
  Country       Code                                    Description
1   Spain B.SP.03089       A random phrase describing the code info
2      UK D.UK.00035 Another random phrase describing the code info
...
```

This data.frame was obtained from a list like

```
> Results
1 Spain-B.SP.03089-A random phrase describing the code info
2 UK-D.UK.00035-Another random phrase describing the code info
```

Using `aux <- str_split(Results,"-")` and `Country <- unlist(aux)[seq(1,length(unlist(aux)),by=3)]` and equivalent for the other 2 var. As you know it's easy to export that to an xlsx by using `write.xlsx()`

So my problem is that I want to export that data.frame to an xlsx with the 1st column to be Country, the 2nd Code and from there a column for every single word of Description var. Take into account that the phrases have different length.

I tried to use again `str_split` and things like that but I cannot get a solution or even to not get lost.

Comment: Find your favorite package for writing to xlsx and iterate through each line of your `ResultsFrame`. Just prior to writing, expand your `Description` to multiple columns using `strsplit(x, " ")`.

Comment: `a column for every single word of Description var.` ? That's a rather strange request. Why do you want that? That's not a useful form for an Excel sheet. If you want that though, the *frame* should have a separate column for each word. Modify the code that produces the frame so it splits the description as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after the recommendations I thought fixing the problem with a double for loop, I was trying to do it avoiding it but it was the simplest way. The solution is as it follows:

```
> Description <- unlist(aux)[seq(3,length(unlist(aux)),by=3)]
> Description2 <- str_split(Description," ")
> for (i in 1:length(Description2)){
+   for (j in 1:length(Description2[[i]])) Results[i,j+3] <- Description2[[i]][j]
+ }
> Results$Description <- NULL
```

The last sentence just to drop the column by personal needs. And the final results are

```
  Country       Code    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8
1   Spain B.SP.03089 word1 word2 word3  <NA>  <NA>
2      UK D.UK.00035 word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
...
```

Exporting that to an xlsx gives me what I needed.